# Invert typing letters on custom keyboard

Tags: ipad

every one i create persian custom keyboard.

I am using this code :

```
NSString *text = textPad.text;
NSRange selectedRange = textPad.selectedRange;
text =  [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:selectedRange withString:@"A"];
textPad.text = text;
textPad.selectedRange = selectedRange;
```

but the problem is when user type a word for example HELLO ... writes : OLLEH !!!!!!! the character writes behind last character instead of after that ! my keyboard is persian custom keyboard !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i should change your slectedRange location , add this code  before the last code :

```
 selectedRange.location++;
```